# AWS App flow with integration of AWS cognito and salesforce

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am trying to create a AWS app flow where i want to get AWS cognito data inside Salesforce, cognito will be source and Salesforce will be destination in app flow.

Please let me know how to get AWS cognito in source tab in auth flow, i cant see/add cognito. i can only select source application from the drop down and cant add any other source application.

Comment: Does it mean that users will be created in AWS Cognito User Pool. The end-user will get a login screen for AWS Cognito.  Authentication happens across AWS User Pool. A successful login will lead to salesforce landing page....Kindly confirm.

Comment: If the above understanding is correct, this URL will help https://medium.com/@chaliyarc/how-to-integrate-aws-cognito-as-the-identity-provider-of-wso2-api-manager-for-single-sign-on-ccf92dda7b5a

Comment: @RobinVarghese,thanks for your answer. 
Users are added in Cognito and we need to export all the users data from Cognito to Salesforce, we are trying with AWS AppFlow service but we cant add Cognito in AppFlow, so want to know the other alternatives to achieve this task.

Comment: I am hoping that with 'export all users data' you are not looking for a solution where all users get migrated to Salesforce. Instead, you want to integrate your Salesforce app with AWS Cognito for Authentication & Authorization. If this is the case, please understand the SAML integration and SSO, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-saml-idp-authentication.html

Comment: @RobinVarghese, we dont want to integrate Cognito with Salesforce for authentication, we want to keep exact copy of users in Cognito with Salesforce, if user details are updated  in Cognito  then we need to update the same in salesforce also, salesforce will use this for other purpose,   to achieve this we are trying with AWS AppFlow service.

Comment: So AWS Cognito doesn't have a user export option readily available. In fact there are APIs using which user information can be collected from AWS Cognito. Passwords, will not be accessible though.  This link has more info https://medium.com/@serkhazov/export-users-from-amazon-cognito-user-pool-bf57a128a9fe. Also, Once the bulk user export is done, for subsequent user registrations, you can use AWS Cognito Lambda triggers to populate Salesforce user repo in parallel. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools-working-with-aws-lambda-triggers.html

Comment: @RobinVarghese, thanks for the reply, we are thinking to schedule the job daily to update the salesforce data instead   of triggering Cognito lambda functions for each user,